# Assembly language instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What is the instruction to invert content of a register?

I'm using these two instructions to do an AND logical operation b/w two registers and store its result in 3rd separate register:

```
and ax, dx ; AND operation b/w ax and dx register and storing its result in ax first then 
mov bx, ax ; storing result in bx.
```

Cant it happen simultaneously (I mean and operation and storing result in separate register) in one instruction?

I'm using NASM assembler and AFD debugger.

Comment: What does this have to do with inverting?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't as a single operation can not act upon 3 registers.

You're suggesting that you can do:

```
bx = ax & dx
```

as a single instruction, and that's simply not the case. What you have instead is:

```
ax = ax & dx
bx = ax
```

You could always swap it around:

```
mov bx, ax
and bx, dx
```

but it's still the same number of instructions.